# Restricted Windows Permissions on Network Drives

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions, network-drive

I'm running a clean install of Windows 7 on my HP laptop. I have one user account, so I'm pretty sure that makes me an administrator with all privileges.

I can't perform any file/folder actions on my network drives. I get errors such as "you need permission to perform this action", and I have to go into the folder that the network drive is mapped to in order to make any significant changes. I've checked the permissions and I have all of them.

I'm assuming my user account is part of the administrators group, but I'm not sure because [I'm not allowed to manage users and groups](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/user-groups-in-windows) (I have Windows 7 Home Premium).

Comment: You will need to verify which user group your user is in before we can help.  Please update the question with that information.  Please tell us more about the network drives

Comment: 1) ". I have one user account, so I'm pretty sure that makes me an administrator with all privileges." Uhm, no. That makes you a user with the rights to elevate to higher permissions. 2) What filesystem is in use on the network drive, how is it shared, which permissions.  (A common trap is that with windows shares and NTFS your effecive rights are the least common part of both).

Comment: Oh, well, alright. Thanks @Hennes. My network drives use NTFS, and SYSTEM, Joey, and Administrators all have the same permissions (everything in the list except "Special Permissions"). In the advanced permissions area, all of them have Full Control. Joey is listed as the owner and has all effective permissions. No permissions in Auditing, however. "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings" is what it says there.